# Eclipse-Plugin Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

I am very new to coding and i cant seem to find out why I am getting a syntax error on my work. It says: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete class body. Here is my code:

```
package me.koda;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class BlockListener implements Listener {

    public BlockListener(AntiBlock plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Place Blocks!");
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {

        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {

        }

        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD     + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Break Blocks!");
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }  // <-- this one



    @EventHandler
    public void onBedrockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {

        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if(e.getBlock().getType() == Material.BEDROCK) {
           if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {
               player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You Cannot Place " +         e.getBlock().getType().toString() + " Down!");
               e.setCancelled(true);
               } else player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You May Place " +         e.getBlock().getType().toString() + " Down!");

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD         + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Place Blocks!");

            e.setCancelled(true);

        }   // <--- this one
```

Like I said i am very new to this and all of the help I get is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Every opening brace needs a closing brace. Just count and you will see that there are two missing.

Comment: (By the way, this is kind of why people are picky about coding style; it becomes a lot easier to figure out whether a brace is missing if you know where the brace *should* be.)

Comment: Learn java before learning 3rd party API

Answer (score 0):

You had several problems with **braces**, so I fixed your code:

```
package me.koda;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class BlockListener implements Listener {

    public BlockListener(AntiBlock plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Place Blocks!");
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {

        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {

        }
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD     + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Break Blocks!");
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }



    @EventHandler
    public void onBedrockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {

        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        if(e.getBlock().getType() == Material.BEDROCK) {
            if (!player.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed")) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You Cannot Place " +         e.getBlock().getType().toString() + " Down!");
                e.setCancelled(true);
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You May Place " +         e.getBlock().getType().toString() + " Down!");
            }

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You, " + ChatColor.GOLD         + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " Cant Place Blocks!");

            e.setCancelled(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Compare your code with this and you'll figure out the problems.